# python absolute import of the function

Tags: python

trend.py and test_trend.py are in the same folder. I have a class Trend with a function find_regres_values that is called from a instance method perform_analysis.

trend.py:

```
class Trend:
    def __init__(self, values, trend_type):
        self.all_values = values

    def permorn_analysis(self, first, trend_type):
        #blabla
        vals_reg = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
        find_regres_values(vals_reg, first, trend_type)

    def find_regres_values(vals_reg, first, trend_type):
        #do somethin
        pass
```

in test_trend.py

```
from trend import find_regres_values
class ConsecRegions(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_find_regres_values_decreas_min_before_max(self):
        #initialize some values
        output = find_regres_values(vals_reg, first, trend_type)
        self.assertEqual(output, result)
```

It shows me an error:

```
  File "test_trend.py", line 2, in <module>
    from trend import find_regres_values
ImportError: cannot import name find_regres_values
```

How do I import one function for testing?

Comment: Please add more details about your python version 2.x 3.x

Comment: Your function resides inside a `class`. You will need to import that class and then (instantiate if need) use the method.

Comment: @Tonja fix missing : in code and some lit to real list exemple to test without error. find_regres_values have indentation problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find_regres_values` is a method of the class `Trend`, If you want `find_regres_values` to be its own function then remove the indentation

```
class Trend:
    def __init__(self, values, trend_type):
        self.all_values = values
    def permorn_analysis(self,first,trend_type)
        #blabla
        vals_reg = some list
        find_regres_values(vals_reg, first, trend_type)

def find_regres_values(vals_reg, first, trend_type):
    #do something
```

Comment: in addition if find_regres_values is a class method, self param is missing.

Answer (score 0):

What Python version you use?

If Python 3.x:

Create empty file `__init__.py`

For correct import use this code:

```
from trend import Trend
```

and edit call of method:

```
from trend import Trend

class ConsecRegions(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_find_regres_values_decreas_min_before_max(self):
        #initialize some values
        output = Trend.find_regres_values(vals_reg, first, trend_type)
        self.assertEqual(output, result)
```

For information:

In file trend.py after permorn_analysis method insert a colon.